# Links Browser via Tor

Tags: proxy, tor, privoxy, lynx, elinks

Is it possible to force the Links text browser to use Tor? Links itself contains only socks4a proxy options, which is no good for Tor current. Specifying Privoxy, with Privoxy forwarding to Tor, using http/s proxy Links options doesn't work. Attempting to set http/s environment proxy to Privoxy doesn't work.

How can Links be made to use Tor?

Answer (score 0):

I know you specifically asked about the [Links web browser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Links_%28web_browser%29), but is it possible for you to use [ELinks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELinks) instead? It is a fork of Links and can be found in most official repositories. ELinks can connect to Tor using [Torsocks](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torsocks.git/), a wrapper to torify applications.

---

Installing [Torsocks on Debian](https://packages.debian.org/buster/torsocks) based distributions:

```
# apt install torsocks
```

Starting Tor:

```
# systemctl start tor.service
```

Running ELinks with Torsocks:

```
$ torsocks elinks https://check.torproject.org
```